# how to use this.setState to update state of react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update the state of react app

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  chatid: 0,
  uniqueid: 0,
  safe: 0
};
}
```

this is the function that i'm calling to change the state.

```
 return_uniqueid() {
console.log("entered function:unique_ID");
var tempid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 + 1);
console.log("tempid:" + tempid);
this.setState({ uniqueid: tempid });
console.log("uniqueid: " + this.state.uniqueid);
}
```

this is the output from console

```
  entered function:unique_ID 
  tempid:714 
  uniqueid: 0
```

The value of uniqueid won't change. How to change the value of `uniqueid`?

I'm calling the function from here:

```
   <form>
      <fieldset>
        <button onClick={this.return_uniqueid.bind(this)}>
          get your ID
        </button>
        <h3 id = "idHeading">your ID is: </h3>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use a form there... There is no input or anything like that... It's just a simple button... Also if you do an arrow function you do not need to bind...

Change to this and it will work:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { chatid: 0, uniqueid: 0, safe: 0 };

  handleGetId = () => {
    console.log('entered function:unique_ID');
    var tempid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 + 1);
    console.log('tempid:' + tempid);
    this.setState({ uniqueid: tempid });
    console.log('uniqueid: ' + this.state.chatid);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3 id="idHeading">your ID is: {this.state.uniqueid} </h3>
        <button onClick={this.handleGetId}>get your ID</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a working example of the same: https://codesandbox.io/s/8267jjy4oj

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState` is asynchronous by nature. So you wont get updated value on next statement.

You can use callback function to get updated state.

```
this.setState({ uniqueid: tempid }, () => {
   console.log(this.state.uniqueid); //This will log update value
});
```

There is also typo in your question

```
return_uniqueid() {
   console.log("entered function:unique_ID");
   var tempid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 + 1);
   console.log("tempid:" + tempid);
   this.setState({ uniqueid: tempid });
   //you are printing this.state.chatid which is never changed.
   console.log("uniqueid: " + this.state.chatid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't get updated state value to next statement.

1. Use callback function

   ```
   this.setState({ uniqueid: tempid }, () => { console.log("uniqueid: ", this.state.uniqueid);});
   ```
2. Check state value in render because whenever state updates automatically render method will call. So you can check required value in render method. Just put console log inside render method.

   ```
   render() {  console.log("uniqueid: ", this.state.uniqueid);}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should be clear about setState that When to use it and why to use it. So I think it will help you to correct your confusion.
 “Understanding ReactJS — setState” @btmpl https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b